# Unallocated HD- recuperar ficheiros

Tags: gparted

[Translated from Portuguese]

Good morning. My laptop does not start, so I made a bootable pen drive with Ubuntu to try and recover the files from the hard drive. When I try to access the HDD, the system shows the drive as "Unknown".

[image: Disks]

GParted shows the same message.

[image: GParted]

Is there is any way to recover the files?

[Original]

Bom dia
O meu portátil não inicia e fiz uma pen bootavel com o ubunto para tentar recuperar os ficheiros do HD.
Quando tento acessar ao HD não consigo, diz Unkown.
E fui ao GParted e aparece o que está na foto. Se houver alguma maneira de recuperar os ficheiros fico muito agradecida

Answer (score 1):

Your 500GB hard drive is showing inconsistent partition data between Disks and Gparted. Data recovery is possible, but not easy. If you have a recent backup, it would be easiest to install a new hard drive and start fresh. If you do not have backups, then a professional data recovery service may be the best option.

Remember to always make backups.

[Portuguese Translation (via Google Translate)]

Seu disco rígido de 500 GB está mostrando dados de partição inconsistentes entre Discos e Gparted. A recuperação de dados é possível, mas não é fácil. Se você tiver um backup recente, será mais fácil instalar um novo disco rígido e começar do zero. Se você não tiver backups, um serviço profissional de recuperação de dados pode ser a melhor opção.

Lembre-se de sempre fazer backups.

Comment: Eu atualizo ps ficheiros guardados online a cada semana, mas tenho trabalhos muito importantes desta semana que precisava mesmo de recuperar. Não há hipótese  de o fazer através do Ubuntu?ou terei mesmo de colocar o HD noutro PC e tentar por essa via?

Comment: Eu atualizo ps ficheiros guardados online a cada semana, mas tenho trabalhos muito importantes desta semana que precisava mesmo de recuperar. Não há hipótese  de o fazer através do Ubuntu?ou terei mesmo de colocar o HD noutro PC e tentar por essa via?

Comment: Os dados da partição em seu disco rígido estão errados, o que geralmente indica um problema sério com o dispositivo. Você pode recuperar os dados com ferramentas como TestDisk, ddRescue ou PhotoRec, mas o processo será complicado e estressante.